# I need to change the icon on Google Chrome on Taskbar

Tags: malware

I downloaded some malware, but got rid of it quick. All's well now, but it did this.

[image]

It's the Chrome program, but named Internet Explorer, also bearing the same icon.

It seems that the shortcut opens up Internet Explorer, yet the rest of the menu options are from Google Chrome, as such:

[image]

Opening the file location opens a window to a Google Chrome file, where the icon there is still Chrome's.

Also, I traced the Chrome file through some folders here and there, it seems that this shortcut's file location jumps to an Internet Explorer shortcut and THAT shortcut jumps to my \Roaming\Browsers directory to a file called iexplore.bat.exe which I assume is the Internet Explorer executable

I'd love to change that back, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`iexplore.bat.exe` is *not* the correct filename for Internet Explorer.

It should be `iexplore.exe`, and it should be located in one of the following directories:

- `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer`

Additionally, the executable should be signed by Microsoft, something you can check by right clicking the file, selecting "*Properties*", and clicking on the "*Digital Signatures*" tab. Selecting a signature and clicking "*Details*" will give you further information:

[image: Digital Signatures Tab of File Properties]

If this tab is not present, then the file is not signed.

---

Some follow up questions:

1. Are you sure you removed the malware?
2. Did you reboot and confirm?

Comment: I rebooted it just a while ago since I had to do some stuff. I had to restore my "Google Chrome" to it's starter settings and now when I open a new tab on this "Chrome", it opens to a plain browser bar with a summer.png
the link of it is https:// search.safefinder. com/?st=dn&data15=0&q=

As for having removed the malware, I am performing a deep scan right now. Yet my quick scan did show 1 threat which it removed.
Will notify with any changes.

Comment: Okay, my Malwarebytes program removed a bunch of adware and my deep scan was all clear. The "Chrome" problem is still there though. Basically I can't find Google Chrome on my PC, only one .exe that opens the program that I showed a screenshot of above. Internet Explorer but it opens Chrome and if I pin it to my taskbar and open it, it opens a really weird Internet Explorer..